# Can't access my website after trying to move it to another server

Tags: apache, dns

I want to move my website to my new virtual server that I bought from another service provider.

I installed Apache Webserver, created a virtuzal host for the website and I changed the DNS in my actual service provider's admin panel pointing to the new server's IP address.

I then realized that I can't access mysql to export my database and I disabled the domain on the new server, changed the DNS back in my old admin, but now I get a ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED when I try to call the website.

I don't find anything on Google, because everybody wants me to delete browser cookies (which I did), but that doesn't help.

What can I do for getting back the old website and being able to export my MySQL database?

Comment: You can always access your old site by IP. If you've forgotten what this is your provider might publish that information on the control panel for the server.

Comment: Thanks! I simply deleted the virtual host again and now I can access the site on the old server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may well be that your DNS records are still propagating and you need to wait. Try adding an entry in your hosts file to point to the "old" site URL and hit it in your browser. If it works then it's the DNS not completed propagating. Otherwise your error looks like an Apache issue not a MySQL issue.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I simply deleted the virtual host again and the old site is working now. I will move the site again, after I exported the database. So you were right, it was probably rather an apache problem.

Comment: Cool. Make sure your apache is listening correctly to the incoming domain name. If it's not in your config it will reject it get the error you got.

Answer (score 0):

I simply deleted the virtual host on the new server for the domain and I was able to access the "old" site immediately.

It's still possible, that the DNS just finished propagating, like @George said, but it's very unlikely.